# Always on VPN (IKEv2) on IOS 14

Tags: vpn, iphone, ios

I want to use VPN (IKEv2) on my iphone 7 (ios 14)
but faced with some unexpected problem:

```
Mar 24 13:59:36 ingrid-common charon: 08[NET] received packet: from _CLIENT_IP_[55169] to _SERVER_IP_[500] (1196 bytes)
Mar 24 13:59:36 ingrid-common charon: 08[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(REDIR_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) ]
Mar 24 13:59:36 ingrid-common charon: 08[IKE] _CLIENT_IP_ is initiating an IKE_SA
Mar 24 13:59:36 ingrid-common charon: 08[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
Mar 24 13:59:36 ingrid-common charon: 08[IKE] received proposals unacceptable
Mar 24 13:59:36 ingrid-common charon: 08[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Mar 24 13:59:36 ingrid-common charon: 08[NET] sending packet: from _SERVER_IP_[500] to _CLIENT_IP_[55169] (36 bytes)
```

then message repeat all time, like : `"sending packet: from _SERVER_IP_[500] to _CLIENT_IP_[55169] (36 bytes)"`

I follow this tutorial to setup my connection: (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Seems other device such macbook/win laptops works well but not iphone (

I have no idea what is wrong.
If anyone already fixed on phone please help.

don't want switch back to android in order to be under vpn all time

Comment: Try without specifying any cipher suites. Works for me from Windows and iOS. I also recommend using Let’s Encrypt.

Comment: omg.. that works! Thx so much!

Comment: @DanielB only two things - why it works? ) what behind of this solution?
and what do u mean by using Let’s Encrypt - give me some example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the guide you link to, the “server” side is restricted to the following cipher suites:

> ```
> ike=chacha20poly1305-sha512-curve25519-prfsha512,aes256gcm16-sha384-prfsha384-ecp384,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
> esp=chacha20poly1305-sha512,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!
> ```

This isn’t *bad*, but it can prevent certain clients from connecting if they want to use different algorithms.

That’s what happens here, in your log:

> ```
> Mar 24 13:59:36 ingrid-common charon: 08[IKE] received proposals unacceptable
> ```

When my iPhone (iOS 14.4.1) connects to my VPN server, it proposes the following cipher suites (encryption, prf, integrity, DH/ECP params):

1. AES256-CBC + HMAC-SHA2-256 + HMAC-SHA2-256-128 + modp2048
2. AES256-CBC + HMAC-SHA2-256 + HMAC-SHA2-256-128 + ecp256
3. AES256-CBC + HMAC-SHA2-256 + HMAC-SHA2-256-128 + modp1536
4. AES128-CBC + HMAC-SHA1 + HMAC-SHA1-96 + modp1024
5. 3DES + HMAC-SHA1 + HMAC-SHA1-96 + modp1024

The selected proposal (I defined no restrictions) is #1. It offers very strong security and integrity.

---

As for the certificate, the guide recommends a self-signed certificate. With Let’s Encrypt, you can instead automatically obtain trusted certificates. I recommend using `acme.sh` for this. I have a symlink in `/etc/ipsec.d/certs` to `/root/.acme.sh/...` and manually placed the root and intermediate certificates in `/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts`. My renew hook is `systemctl restart ipsec`.

Let’s Encrypt certificates work out of the box on iOS and Windows devices.

Comment: "no restrictions" is key here. I've had the same problem and just removing cipher suites from /etc/ipsec.conf solved it.